# Trying to create an app through NiceGUI.I have a button on which an API is called .But API takes time to respond and app loses connection. Any fixes?

Tags: python, nicegui

I'm creating an app using NiceGUI (Python). I have a button which upon getting clicked makes an API call. However that API takes a lot of time to do the work in the backend and the app loses connection and shows the error as:

> "Trying to connect. Lost connection".

Is there any fix for this. Can I prevent the app to lose connection and stay active while the API does its work ?

Trying to make an API call which takes a lot of time to do the work in the backend and in the mean time app loses connection. I want the app to stay active while API does the work. I cannot tweak the time of API to do the work because it's a pre built API. How can I make the app stay active ?

Comment: This is where nicegui shines. Async handling of long running tasks. You can even have a spinner/progress bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been discussed [here](https://github.com/zauberzeug/nicegui/discussions/1046):

> You should offload all heavy work with async/await. NiceGUI (and the underlying FastAPI) are async frameworks. That means, no io-bound or cpu-bound tasks should be directly executed on the main thread but rather be "awaited".

You should have a look into [asyncio's `run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) which allows you to await long-running tasks while the UI stays responsive.

Comment: could you be more specific? https://github.com/justpy-org/justpy/blob/master/examples/charts_tutorial/stock_charts/stock_test2.py e.g. has a call to run_in_executor which requires accesss to the loop variable. How is this done in nicegui?

Comment: You can use `asyncio.get_event_loop()` to get the event loop.

Comment: thx for the hint https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/nicegui_widgets/blob/main/ngwidgets/background.py is what i am currently trying